# How to format Matplotlib secondary y-axis datetime values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, yaxis

I am attempting to plot a line graph superimposed on a bar graph using matplotlib. The data has plotted correctly, however, the secondary y-axis describing the forecasted start time is being output incorrectly. All values for Forecasted Start Time are rounded off to the hour e.g. (13:00, 14:00, etc) but when plotted are converted to 11:40, 12:13:20, etc on the y-axis, as so:

[Forecasted Start Time csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJlPp.png)

[Forecasted Start Time and Event Length vs. Forecast Run graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwX74.png)

The code to produce this image is as follows:

```
en1 = []
en2 =[]

en1 = np.array(fh.loc(axis=0)[0:44])
en2 = np.array(ev.loc(axis=0)[0:44])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.bar(en1,en2,color='gainsboro')
plt.ylabel('Forecasted Event Length')

plt.xticks(rotation='90')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
mn, mx = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylabel('Forecasted Start Time')
color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')


ax2.plot(fh,start, marker='o')

plt.legend()
```

Any ideas on how to plot the actual datetime values from the csv correctly on the secondary y-axis would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to plot on the axis object using `ax.bar` and `ax2.plot` instead of `plt.bar` and `plt.plot`.

You can use the axis formatter to do this:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

Comment: The issue still persists even after the change to plot on the axis object. Is there any way to set the ytick values on the secondary y-axis?

Comment: See edit above. You can use the dateformatter assuming you have datetime objects

Comment: It looks like I was having some issues with the pd.to_datetime function when I was initially defining my variables. The dateformatter worked perfectly. Thank you very much!